# Why does signalR stop pinging after 20minutes here?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, websocket, signalr

I'm using signalr-no-jquery v0.1.10 to make a client - server connection. The problem is the client stops pinging after 20 minutes, I'm guessing it is some sort of default value in miliseconds. Where could I change this timeout to a higher value? The documentation is not exact or helpful in this version of signalR on how to do this. Maybe someone recognises where the config needs to be. I know the start() function can receive config but can it change the ping timeout for example? Again, the docs are scarce in this version of signalR. Currently my setup looks like this:

```
export const createSocketConnection = () => {
  const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

  return hubConnection(`${URL}/signalr`, { useDefaultPath: false })
};

export const createSocketProxy = (connection, hubName) => {
  return connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
};

export const createSocketChannel = (eventName, proxy) =>

  eventChannel((emit) => {
    const messageHandler = (...data) => {
      emit(data);
    };
    proxy.on(eventName, messageHandler);

    return () => { };
  });

export const startSocket = (socket) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.start().done(() => resolve());
  });

export const stopSocket = (socket) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.stop().done(() => resolve());
  });
```

Comment: 20 mins sounds like the IIS AppPool idle timeout: https://inthetechpit.com/2019/09/12/app-pool-set-idle-time-out-iis-server/